# Amazon Web Services (AWS) Products plugin Error

Tags: plugin, amazon

Having an issue w/ this EE add-on where if an Amazon product isn't found with a specific ID I get this error:

```
You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing }, or a missing {/if}.

Parser State: Unexpected end of Template “article/index” on line 157; expected ENDIF tag for opening on line 46 in Template “layouts/.html-layout”.
```

Here's how I'm using the tags in my template:

```
{if amazon_product_asin_or_isbn}
<div class="panel PanelProduct clearfix">
  {exp:aws_products:search
    item_id="{amazon_product_asin_or_isbn}"
    associate_id="{associate_id}"
    public_key="{public_key}" private_key="{private_key}"
  }
  <div class="PanelProduct-imageContainer left">
    <img src="{img_large}" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="PanelProduct-content right">
    <h3 class="Article-subheading">Related Product:</h3>
    <h4 class="PanelProduct-heading">{product_name}</h4>
    <div class="PanelProduct-info">{catalog_type} | {publisher}</div>
    <a class="button small u-mediumTopMargin u-noMarginBot" href="{amazon_link}" target="_blank">{best_price} on Amazon</a>
  </div>
  {/exp:aws_products:search}
</div>
{/if}
```

I then tried using this if statement within the tags to only render the product panel if there is a product found:

```
{if aws_count > 0}   {/if}
```

But then I get this error in the template:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: !-- ra:000000003bf7ea8400000001087a7b32 --

Filename: aws_products/pi.aws_products.php

Line Number: 237
```

It seems like any if statements within the tags break the plugin. So how can I integrate the tags in a way that detects if there's a valid product ID filled in without totally breaking the page?

Using AWS Products 3.1.0 on EE 2.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Louis at Hop Studios has posted an [update of this plugin](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/amazon-web-services-aws-products) which fixes the above issue.